# Texture Not Showing Up

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am trying to add a texture onto my triangle but it just shows up as a black triangle. Here is my starting function that gets called:

```
GLuint vao;
GLuint shader_programme;
extern "C" void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API createSimpleWindow()
{



    if (std::this_thread::get_id() == MAIN_THREAD_ID)
    {
        oldContext = glfwGetCurrentContext();

        newContext = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "window", NULL, oldContext);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(newContext);
        // start GLEW extension handler
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        glewInit();

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"
//triangle pts
        float points[] = {
            0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,     0.5f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f
        };
        GLuint vbo = 0;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

         vao = 0;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        //glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vs);
        GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fs);

        shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shader_programme, fs);
        glAttachShader(shader_programme, vs);
        glLinkProgram(shader_programme);

         glUseProgram(shader_programme);
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        int width, height, nrComponents;
        unsigned char *data = stbi_load("/Users/roma/Desktop/Escape Tech/BitBucketRepos/blankpluginGLFW/BlankPlugin/PluginSource/source/container2.png", &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);

        writeToLog("before data");
        if (data) {
            writeToLog("data contained!!!!!!");
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        }
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_programme, "texture1"), 0);
        //glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(newContext, key_callback);
    }
    else
    {
        writeToLog("not main thread");
    }
}
```

Here is the function that gets called in a while loop:

```
extern "C" void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API windowMainLoop()
{

    writeToLog("render loop");
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(newContext);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // loop until the window closed
    if (!glfwWindowShouldClose(newContext)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (std::this_thread::get_id() == MAIN_THREAD_ID)
        {
            // bind Texture
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            glUseProgram(shader_programme);
            glBindVertexArray(vao);
            // draw points 0-3 from the currently bound VAO with current in-use shader
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
            glfwSwapBuffers(newContext);
            // poll the events
            glfwPollEvents();

        }
        //switch back to old context
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(oldContext);
        writeToLog("finished render loop");
    }

}
```

My "if (data)" statement results in the text begin written to the log so I know the image is being loaded properly but I cannot figure out why the triangle is black.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the setup arrays of generic vertex attribute data. Each attribute tuple consist of 5 components (x, y, z, u, v):

> ```cpp
> float points[] = {
>     0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,    0.5f, 1.0f,
>     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
>    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f
> };
> ```

So the stride parameter has to be `5 * siezof(GLfloat)` rather than  `6 * siezof(GLfloat)`:

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

---

The 2nd parameter of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) is the size of the buffer in bytes. Your buffer consists of 15 (5 * 3) elements of type `GLfloat`. So the size is `15 * sizeof(float)` rather than `9 * sizeof(float)`:

```cpp
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 15 * sizeof(float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

---

Since the format of the file is [.png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) the last parameter of `stbi_load` should be set 4, to ensure that a 4 channels of the texture are get:

```cpp
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("?.png", &width, &height, &nrComponents, 4);
```

The format and internal format of [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) have to be `GL_RGBA`.
By default the texture minifying function (`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`) is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` (see [`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)). Since you don't use [mip mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), the parameter has to be changed to `GL_LINEAR`:

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: I fixed that but the screen is still black :/

Comment: The triangle is still black but the whole triangle is at least showing up now (only part of it was before but I just ignored it).

Comment: @steph Another issue when you read the texture. (3rd part of the answer)